# Keras regression | Get a single prediction from a model fitted with multiple y parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code to create a custom loss function using an additional feature from the dataset (which is not an input feature) as an argument. The code works fine without errors but I want to make sure it makes predictions for the correct 'Y'.

```
    def custom_loss(data, y_pred):

        y_true = data[:, 0]
        feature = data[:, 1]
        return K.mean(K.square((y_pred - y_true) + K.std(y__pred - feature)))

    def create_model():
        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=1, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))

    (train, test) = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

    model = models.create_model(train["X"].shape[1])
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-2, decay=1e-3/200)
    model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=opt)


    model.fit(x=train["X"], y=train[["Y", "feature"]], validation_data=(test["X"], test[["Y", "feature"]]), batch_size = 8, epochs=90)

    predY = model.predict(test["X"]) # what does the model predict here?
```

When I make predictions using this model, does it make predictions for only 'Y' or a combination of Y and the additional feature because model.fit( ) takes both 'Y' and 'feature' as the y parameter to train but model.predict( ) only gives the one output. If the predictions are a combination of Y and the additional feature, how can I extract only Y?

Answer (score 0):

The model predicts 'Y' only. Loss function is not calling when predicting.